# Qué códigos de color en CSS cargan más rápido

Tags: css

En los archivos CSS, ¿es mejor poner el código del color o poner su nombre en letras? Me refiero a nivel de carga de los estilos.

Por ejemplo, ¿da lo mismo poner `color: white;` que `color: #fff;`?

¿Cuál de ellos cargaría más rápido?

Comment: En lo personal uso el código hexadecimal, y mis páginas cargan rápido, las reviso con speedtest web de Google para verificar su velocidad de carga. Adicional puedes googlear buscando la paleta de colores html, buscas el color que deseas y te da el hexadecimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según he leído por Internet, la mejor práctica es usar código hexadecimal de 6 dígitos (no se distinguen mayúsculas de minúsculas).

Si usas colores no primarios, puede ser que depende el navegador que uses, tengan diferentes colores definidos.

Por otro lado, si deseas añadir pequeñas modificaciones a los colores, también se usan los colores rgba: `rgba(255,255,255,0.8);` Ese `0.8` al final es un parámetro `alpha` para darle más o menos opacidad al color.

Comment: "Según he leído por Internet" no es una fuente en sí, debes citar sitios de confianza donde se indique y soporte lo que pones en la respuesta.

Comment: Como observación, un usuario de SOen hizo unas pruebas con JS y determinó que los códigos en hexadecimal tardan menos en cargarse. Aquí su respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27531794

Answer (score 1):

Considero que tanto con un formato como con otro el sistema funciona correctamente, no obstante poner el código exadecimal ( #fff ) quizá sea un pelín más rápido.
Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

No hay respuesta mejor o peor. Simplemente **acuerda** con tu equipo un **estándard** y síguelo.

O simplemente cuando empieces en un proyecto existente probablemente se usará alguno de estos estándares y tendrás que seguirlo.

Comentar que los nombres para colores se ampliaron con la especificación CSS3. [Aquí](https://www.quackit.com/css/color/charts/css_color_names_chart.cfm) puedes ver una lista completa.

Particularmente me parece una cantidad de nombres más que suficiente para cualquier proyecto. Así que trabajar únicamente con nombres de colores me parece una opción perfectamente válida.

Lo que a veces pasa es que el diseño no depende de ti, y muchas veces tienes que implementar algo que te ha pedido un maquetador, usando unos colores concretos que no puedes/debes cambiar. Y si ese color no tiene nombre dentro del estándard CSS3, deberás usar rgb/rgba/hex.